# Create AD Object - Not Exchange

Tags: powershell, active-directory, contacts

I am currently trying to create an Active Directory contact object in a specific OU in our Active Directory. I am not looking at using Exchange PowerShell. I would like to do this via normal PowerShell directly in to AD.

I have looked online and found that I can create a contact using the below command, this creates it in a specific OU.

```
New-ADObject -Name SaraDavisSGTContact3 -Type contact -Path "OU=SGTestOU,OU=Contacts,DC=example,DC=Example,DC=local"
```

How would I also get it to add other attributes such as `mail` (email address), first name, surname, etc.? I tried `-Mail example.com`, etc., but this didn't work.

Please bear in mind I will eventually try and get this to read from a CSV to do in bulk, so the simplier the code the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-OtherAttributes` Parameter to add additional attributes.
See [New-ADObject MSDN Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617260.aspx)

```
New-ADObject -name SaraDavisSGTContact3 -Type Contact -path "OU=SGTestOU,OU=Contacts,DC=example,DC=Example,DC=local" -OtherAttributes @{
'mail'="sara@gmail.com";
'proxyAddresses'="sara@gmail.com";
'givenName'="Sara";
'sn'="Davis";
'displayname'="Sara Davis"
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks! :)